# C# WMI: Throws an error when I try to enable/disable PPPoE adapter

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to enable/disable my PPPoE adapter according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16867003).
It works great with normal adapters but not with PPPoE which throws an error saying :

> An error occurred while querying for WMI data: Invalid method Parameter(s)

The adapter name is correct I used WMI Query tool for that purpose but I have no idea what params need to be set. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

Here's the code I used:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Name = 'WAN Miniport (PPPOE)'");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                queryObj.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
                //Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found my way around with [DotRas](http://dotras.codeplex.com/) here's the code to connect/disconnect PPPoE connection (AKA dial up):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using DotRas;

namespace Test_Reconnect_PPPoE
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Connect
            using (RasDialer dialer = new RasDialer())
            {
                dialer.EntryName = "Your Entry (Connection Name)";
                dialer.PhoneBookPath = RasPhoneBook.GetPhoneBookPath(RasPhoneBookType.User);
                dialer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                dialer.Dial();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            }
            // Disconnect
            RasConnection conn = RasConnection.GetActiveConnections().Where(o => o.EntryName == "Your Entry (Connection Name)").FirstOrDefault();
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.HangUp();
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone.